# mqtt on esp8266 with micropython

Tags: python, mqtt, micropython

I have a modem and four Esp8266 and a Raspberry Pi. I want to control Esp with Python language via internet. I have read this project.

> https://randomnerdtutorials.com/micropython-mqtt-esp32-esp8266/

Instead of ESP2, I implemented the code on Windows. But I got the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ustruct'.
Is there a way for me to remotely check the Raspberry Pi and ESPs using Windows?
Of course I want to use MQTT.
[This photo shows what I have described.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yay8G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`ustruct` is a [MicroPython Module](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/ustruct.html) that is available on all if not most MicroPython firmwares ( including the Win32 version of MicroPython)

If you need to / want to port your code to Cpython (on windows or other) that should not be too much work as the two are quite compatible.

as your project needs network capabilities using the Windows port of MicroPython is not an option as neither the Unix nor the Widows ports come with a network stack you compile/download a windows port of MicroPython